# Why all the true positives are classified as true negatives in the machine learning model?

Tags: python, random-forest, prediction

I fit a random forest model for the data. I divided my dataset into training and testing in the ratio of 70:30 and trained the model. I got an accuracy of 80% for the test data. Then I took a benchmark dataset and tested the model with that dataset. That dataset only contained data with true labels(1). But when I get the prediction for the benchmark dataset using the model all the true positives are classified as true negatives. Accuracy is 90%. Why is that? Is there a way to interpret this?

```
X = dataset.iloc[:, 1:11].values    
y=dataset.iloc[:,11].values

X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test=train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.3,random_state=1,shuffle='true')

XBench_test=benchmarkData.iloc[:, 1:11].values
YBench_test=benchmarkData.iloc[:,11].values

classifier=RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=35,criterion='entropy',max_depth=30,min_samples_split=2,min_samples_leaf=1,max_features='sqrt',class_weight='balanced',bootstrap='true',random_state=0,oob_score='true')
classifier.fit(X_train,y_train)
y_pred=classifier.predict(X_test)

y_pred_benchmark=classifier.predict(XBench_test)

print("Accuracy on test data: {:.4f}".format(classifier.score(X_test, y_test)))\*This gives 80%*\

print("Accuracy on benchmark data: {:.4f}".format(classifier.score(XBench_test, YBench_test))) \*This gives 90%*\
```

Comment: Can you provide more detail on how you did this with code samples?

Comment: @jawsem I added my code in the post

Comment: What is the bench mark data and what is the data you out using for train and test?

Comment: @jawsem train set contains landslide data from one country and the benchmark dataset contain landslide data from another country

Comment: What do you mean when you say all the True positives are classified as True negatives?  If a model is classifying True positives incorrectly that is considered a False negative.  Also using "predict" is not going to give you the whole picture.  The model could performing correctly at other thresholds than .5.  I would try using predict_proba and look at different thresholds of performance.

Comment: Most of the actual landslide locations in the benchmark dataset are classified as non-landslide locations. Benchmark dataset is an unseen dataset given for the model to see how it performs on other datasets. The model was trained and tested using a different dataset.

Answer (score 0):

I'll take a shot at providing a better way to interpret your results.  In cases where you have an imbalanced data set accuracy is not going to be a good way to measure your performance.

Here is a common example:

Imagine you have a disease that is present in only .01% of people.  If you predict no one has the disease you have an accuracy of 99.99% but your model is not a good model.

In this example it appears your benchmark data set (commonly referred to as a test dataset) has imbalanced classes and you are getting an accuracy of 90% when you call the classifier.score method.  In this case, accuracy is not a good way to interpret the model.  You should instead look at other metrics.

Other common metrics may be to look at [precision and recall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precision_and_recall) to determine how your model is performing.  In this case since all True positives are predicted as negative your precision AND your recall would be 0, meaning your model is not differentiating very well.

Going further if you have imbalanced classes it may be better to check different thresholds of scores and look at metrics like [ROC_AUC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Receiver_operating_characteristic).  These metrics look at the probability scores outputted by the model (predict_proba for sklearn) and test different thresholds.  Perhaps your model works well at a lower threshold and the positive cases consistently score higher than the negative cases.

Here is an additional article about [ROC_AUC](https://towardsdatascience.com/understanding-auc-roc-curve-68b2303cc9c5).

Sci-kit learn has a few different metric scores you can use they are located [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html).

Here is one way you could implement ROC AUC into your code.

```
X = dataset.iloc[:, 1:11].values    
y=dataset.iloc[:,11].values

X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test=train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.3,random_state=1,shuffle='true')

XBench_test=benchmarkData.iloc[:, 1:11].values
YBench_test=benchmarkData.iloc[:,11].values

classifier=RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=35,criterion='entropy',max_depth=30,min_samples_split=2,min_samples_leaf=1,max_features='sqrt',class_weight='balanced',bootstrap='true',random_state=0,oob_score='true')
classifier.fit(X_train,y_train)
#use predict_proba
y_pred=classifier.predict_proba(X_test)

y_pred_benchmark=classifier.predict_proba(XBench_test)

from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score
## instead of measuring accuracy use ROC AUC)
print("Accuracy on test data: {:.4f}".format(roc_auc_score(X_test, y_test)))\*This gives 80%*\

print("Accuracy on benchmark data: {:.4f}".format(roc_auc_score(XBench_test, YBench_test))) \*This gives 90%*\
```